# Contact Form 7 Conditional Redirection Without Sending Mail

Tags: wordpress, redirect, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 where I have two fields (amongst others) namely "Service" and "Applicant Pin". What I intend to do is, if some specific Services are chosen along with a matching Applicant Pin, I don't want the form to send email, rather redirect to another page. I have seen a lot of solutions but none work for me. Here is the last code I tried:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_check_redirection', 10, 1 );

function wpcf7_check_redirection( $contact_form ) {
    
    //Get the form ID
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();
    
    if( $form_id == 2852 ) {
                
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $cf7_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        
        $service = $cf7_data['service'];
        $pincode = $cf7_data['applicant_pin'];
        $saltLake = array(700064, 700091, 700097, 700098, 700105, 700106, 700059, 700101, 700135, 700102, 700157, 700159);

        if ( (($service = "Full Package for Single") || ($service = "Full Package for Couples")) && ( in_array($pincode, $saltLake)) ) { 
                    $contact_form->skip_mail = true;
                    wp_redirect("https://example.com/services/");
                    exit;
                }
    }
    
}
```

In the developer tools, under the network section, I see a 302 status and fetch / Redirect Type for https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/2852/feedback and the console shows an error

```
{
    "code": "invalid_json",
    "message": "The response is not a valid JSON response."
}
```

I am at my wits' end. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version, it appears you tried to use the comparison function `=` which is a setter (x will equal value), and not a comparison (if x is equal to value).

I've used the `wpcf7_skip_mail` filter to prevent the mail, but also added the redirection script to include in the footer, using `wpcf7mailsent` javascript event listener.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_check_redirection', 10, 1 );

function wpcf7_check_redirection( $contact_form ) {

    if ( 2744 === $contact_form->id() ) {

        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $cf7_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            $service  = $cf7_data['service'];
            $pincode  = $cf7_data['applicant_pin'];
            $saltLake = array( 700064, 700091, 700097, 700098, 700105, 700106, 700059, 700101, 700135, 700102, 700157, 700159 );
            if ( in_array( $service, array( 'Full Package for Single', 'Full Package for Couples' ), true ) && in_array( $pincode, $saltLake, true ) ) {
                // Proper way to add skip mail.
                add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail', '__return_true' );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'dd_add_cf7_redirect' );
function dd_add_cf7_redirect() {
    if ( is_page( 123 ) ) { // replace with your page id.
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
                // Redirect to your location.
                location = 'https://www.example.com/your-redirect-uri/';
            }, false);
        </script>
        <?php }
}
```

Comment: The code stops the email, but the redirection is not working. There are no errors in the console though.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another possibility.